# Removing StopWords from a Character using R

Tags: r, gsub

Consider that I have the below mentioned String;

```
str_input <- c("Mellanox,Asia, China, India, JAVA, United States, APIs")
```

I have used the below mentioned gsub code which removes my specific StopWords.

```
gsub(paste0("\\b(",paste(location_sw, collapse="|"),")\\b"), "", str_input)
```

where, location_sw consists of my list of stopwords as mentioned below

```
location_sw <- c('Rose', 'Java', 'JAVA', 'Mellanox', 'Microsoft', '144GiB', 'West',
                 'Amazon', 'Channel Asia', 'jClarity', 'APIs')
```

On using the above provided gsub code, I am getting the below mentioned output

```
",Asia, China, India, , United States, "
```

However, I would like the following outcome;

```
"Asia, China, India, United States"
```

I would like to remove the commas present after removing the stopwords. Any inputs will be really helpfull.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach is to `strsplit` the string into a character vector and then taking the `setdiff` with respect to `location_sw`:

```r
out <- setdiff(strsplit(str_input, split = ",\\s*")[[1]], location_sw)
out
#> [1] "Asia"          "China"         "India"         "United States"
```

If necessary, we can `paste` it back to a character:

```r
paste(out, collapse = ", ")
#> [1] "Asia, China, India, United States"
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use

```
str_input <- c("Mellanox,Asia, China, India, JAVA, United States, APIs")
rx <- paste0("(?:,\\s*)*\\b(?:",paste(location_sw, collapse="|"),")\\b")
trimws(gsub(rx, "", str_input), whitespace = "[\\s,]")
## => [1] "Asia, China, India, United States"
```

The `(?:,\\s*)` will match 0 or more occurrences of a comma followed with 0 or more whitespaces.

The trimws with `whitespace = "[\\s,]"` will remove leading and trailing whitespace and commas.

Answer (score 1):

A `base` option:

```
paste(lapply(strsplit(str_input,",|,\\s"), function(x) 
               x[!x %in% location_sw])[[1]],collapse=", ")
    [1] "Asia, China, India, United States"
```